# Why are "hello" (isMaster) commands with topologyVersion timing out?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

To replicate what I’m seeing on Production, I have a standalone MongoDB instance running locally, where the `hello()` admin command (previously `isMaster`) runs till the `maxAwaitTimeMS` and times out, every time:

```js
db.runCommand({
    "hello": 1,
    "topologyVersion": {
      "processId": ObjectId("628c762af984c948c15f8811"),
      "counter": NumberLong(0)
    },
    "maxAwaitTimeMS": 5000,
    "$db": "admin"
});;
```

Note that when 'timing out', the response is still what the client would have expected - what's not clear is why the Mongo server does not return with this immediately, rather than having the query have to run till its `maxAwaitTimeMS` before responding:

```json
{
    "isWritablePrimary" : true,
    "topologyVersion" : {
        "processId" : ObjectId("628c762af984c948c15f8811"),
        "counter" : 0
    },
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
    "maxMessageSizeBytes" : 48000000,
    "maxWriteBatchSize" : 100000,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2022-05-29T11:35:36.011+01:00"),
    "logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes" : 30,
    "connectionId" : 86043,
    "minWireVersion" : 0,
    "maxWireVersion" : 9,
    "readOnly" : false,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

There is no other activity on the server - so it's not an issue of performance or connections otherwise being held up. The query will run as long as the ‘awaitMaxTimeMS’, even when increased to e.g 5 minutes. The issue only occurs where the `topologyVersion` is included in the call, specifically when using the correct `processID` that is returned when first running the query as follows:

```js
// query completes immediately
db.runCommand({
  "hello": 1,
  "$db": "admin"
});

// and the response includes the following:
// { "processId" : ObjectId("628c762af984c948c15f8811") }
```

These calls are being made from Mongo drivers (PyMongo and Ruby Mongo), and we are seeing the same issue on a Production Mongo instance - where `currentOp` is showing many of these `hello()` queries, all of which are timing out.

**My question is, why are these requests timing out and not completing immediately as expected?**

Aside from the noise it creates in the `currentOp` list (with each query hanging around for the 10 seconds) and the curiosity in understanding why, I'd also like this resolved as to help ensure connections aren't otherwise being held up due to this issue. Reducing the `maxAwaitTimeMS` (assuming the Mongo drivers give such control) would feel like hiding the issue. The issue does not seem to be happening while performing a few tests on a replicated MongoDB server.

Comment: can you clarify why do you call `hello` manually?

Comment: @dododo I’m calling it manually here to successfully replicate the issue - but the calls are otherwise coming in regular intervals from the Mongo drivers.

Comment: I can't explain the behavior, but I'm wondering if you want `"maxTimeMS"` instead of `"maxAwaitTimeMS"`.

Comment: The use of `maxAwaitTimeMS` in the query here is matching what's set by the Mongo clients - Pymongo and Ruby Mongo Driver in this case.

Comment: "These calls are being made from Mongo drivers (PyMongo and Ruby Mongo)" Is the question actually about the code written in either Python or Ruby or both? In order to see the problem myself, do I need to write code in one of those? Both? In the code examples starting with `db.runCommand({`, what language is that? Would a Python expert and/or a Ruby expert be expected to have a particular advantage in answering the question?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it's a Mongo question, with the Ruby and Python examples giving context to help explain how I came across the issue and why it's being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what's not clear is why the Mongo server does not return with this immediately, rather than having the query have to run till its maxAwaitTimeMS before responding:

this is expected behavior for a "special" mode for a hello thread called streaming. In 2 words, a client just initiates streaming server's states by sending a hello command and then waits responses from server (without sending requests). So `maxAwaitTimeMS` is a max time which server can wait before sending response to the client.

So yes, it's expected. Waiting can be less than `maxAwaitTimeMS`, for example if server topology has been changed during waiting, but this value sets the top waiting bound and if the server is healthy, you will wait the whole specified period

> I see, so you're saying it's normal behaivour to have many isMaster/hello queries all running up to the maxAwaitTimeMS

if it happens at the same time, then I would vote that they contain different endpoints in `me` field in the response since driver creates a separate `hello` thread for each endpoint

Comment: I see, so you're saying it's normal behaivour to have many `isMaster`/`hello` queries all running up to the `maxAwaitTimeMS`, and that I shouldn't expect them to 'finish' any sooner?

`counter` and `processId` response example is in my original question - where it responds with the same processId that was passed in the request, and the counter still as zero.

I'll need to look into the source code of the client (e.g Ruby Mongo Driver) as it's not clear what the implications would be of it considering the server being down - when it isn't. Thank you for your thoughts here.

Comment: sorry, i messed up a bit logic in my first answer, now it's updated. As I wrote, if you specify `topologyVersion` in hello request then you enable streaming mode where server responds server's state without requesting it from the client side. `maxAwaitTime` setup a max time period which server can wait before streaming server's state back to the client (to not DDOS client). The response can be received before this time is exceeded if the server topology will be changed, but if nothing happens on the server state, you will wait the whole time

Comment: Thank you @dododo, helpful to ultimately discover that it's 'just the way Mongo works' and the queries weren't 'hanging' till their timeout but it works this why by design.